# How do I prevent new line \ characters from being output to YAML when I use ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am attempting to write a python dictionary to a yaml file using ruamel.yaml. I need some strings to be explicitly quoted so I pass them to ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString which wraps them in double quotes in output. However, strings that are covered over multiple lines contain \ characters in them in the output. How do I prevent this?

I tried searching for \ with regex after I pass the string to the ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString and replace them with '' but this does not work. I think these characters are added at the time of dumping.

```
S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
string = "The Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale-Validation (PDSS-2) is a scale used to characterise and quantify the various aspects of nocturnal sleep problems in Parkinson's disease (PD). The PDSS-2 is a revised version of the Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale (PDSS)."
st = S(string)
data = {'key': st}

f = open('./yam.yaml', 'w')
yaml= YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.indent(offset = 2, sequence = 4, mapping = 2)
yaml.dump(data, f)
```

Expected:

```
key: "The Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale-Validation (PDSS-2) is a scale used to characterise and quantify the various aspects of nocturnal sleep problems in Parkinson's disease (PD). The PDSS-2 is a revised version of the Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale (PDSS)."
```

Actual:

```
key: "The Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale-Validation (PDSS-2) is a scale used to characterise\
  \ and quantify the various aspects of nocturnal sleep problems in Parkinson's disease\
  \ (PD). The PDSS-2 is a revised version of the Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale (PDSS)."
```

Answer (score 2):

What you see is caused by the line wrapping, that tries to limit the line length to the default of 80 characters, in the output.

If you can live with wider output, then just set `yaml.width` to a larger value:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
YAML = ruamel.yaml.YAML

S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
string = "The Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale-Validation (PDSS-2) is a scale used to characterise and quantify the various aspects of nocturnal sleep problems in Parkinson's disease (PD). The PDSS-2 is a revised version of the Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale (PDSS)."
st = S(string)
data = {'key': st}

yaml= YAML()
yaml.width = 2048
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.indent(offset = 2, sequence = 4, mapping = 2)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
key: "The Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale-Validation (PDSS-2) is a scale used to characterise and quantify the various aspects of nocturnal sleep problems in Parkinson's disease (PD). The PDSS-2 is a revised version of the Parkinson's Disease Sleep Scale (PDSS)."
```

Comment: Unfortunately the spec demands this line width. The spec is optimized for readability I will have certain strings that will be quote long and would not be easily readable.

Comment: As the spec (whatever that is) demands 263 characters, as per your expected output, you can set the width to that. It would help if you clearly explained why you would need double quotes around the values, and/or why the back-quotes in the output are a problem. A proper YAML parser will recreate your `string` on loading if you dump without quotes as well as from your output with backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand why they need quotes for these. They wanted quotes around things like yes and no so they dont become boolean. I think they want consistency. I won't know how big my input will be ahead of time, but it could be much longer.

Comment: "yes" and "no" should not generate a boolean in an up-to-date YAML parser. That was something YAML 1.1 specified and that has been replaced 10 (ten!) years ago.